# Error al Declarar el operador between con PDO en PHP 7

Tags: javascript, php, php7, pdo

disculpa por la molestia, tengo un pequeño problema a la hora de hacer una consulta de fechas con between con PDO y PHP 7.

TABLA: alumnos.

| id | idColegio | idProfesor | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | 2021-03-01 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2021-03-05 |
| 3 | 4 | 6 | 2021-03-06 |
| 4 | 3 | 5 | 2021-03-23 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 | 2021-04-05 |

Nota: No puedo imprimir los datos que están dentro del rango ósea si yo tengo fecha inicial 2021-03-01 y fecha final 2021-03-23, algo estoy haciendo mal por favor me pueden corregir que estoy declarando mal, gracias.

```
"Datos que vienen del controlador y ajax, datos simulados":

$tablaAlumno = "alumnos";
$colColegio = "idColegio"; <-- id tabla de colegio
$idColegio = "5"; 
$colProfesor = "idProfesor"; <-- id tabla profesor
$idProfesor = "3"; <---
$colFecha = "fecha";

$fechaInicio = "2021-03-01";
$fechaFinal = "2021-03-23";


    static public function modeloConsultaFechas($tablaAlumno, $colColegio, $idColegio, $colProfesor, $idProfesor, $colFecha, $fechaInicio, $fechaFinal){

        $data = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tablaAlumno WHERE $colColegio = :$colColegio AND $colProfesor = :$colProfesor AND $colFecha = :$colFecha BETWEEN $fechaInicio AND $fechaFinal");

        $data -> bindParam(":".$colColegio, $idColegio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data -> bindParam(":".$colProfesor, $idProfesor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data -> bindParam(":".$colFecha, $fechaInicio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data -> bindParam(":".$colFecha, $fechaFinal, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $data -> execute();

        return $data -> fetchAll();

        $data -> close();

        $data = null;


}
```

Resultado Final: Así debería quedar, pero no logro realizar la consulta, ayúdenme por favor.

| id | idColegio | idProfesor | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | 2021-03-01 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2021-03-05 |

Comment: :$colColegio <--- carga los datos del controlador que es manipulado por el usuario, yo entiendo así, si le pongo :colColegio tampoco me da el resultado.

Comment: Estoy desactualizado, gracias por pasarme la documentación voy a investigar a ver si logro declarar bien.

Comment: Tu consulta debe quedar así: `SELECT * FROM $tablaAlumno WHERE $colColegio = :colColegio AND $colProfesor = :colProfesor AND $colFecha BETWEEN :fechaInicio AND :fechaFinal` y los parámetros debes pasarlos así: `$data -> bindParam(":colColegio", $idColegio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data -> bindParam(":colProfesor", $idProfesor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data -> bindParam(":fechaInicio", $fechaInicio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data -> bindParam(":fechaFinal", $fechaFinal, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias hermano voy a probarlo.

Comment: Es muy simple: en la **consulta** pones marcadores (en este caso de `:nombre`) **allí donde irían datos**, y luego en los `bindParam`  pasas **cada valor junto a su marcador**, así el SGDB sabrá a qué corresponde cada cosa. Una consulta preparada es como decir el SGBD: *aquí va un dato, pero te lo pasaré luego mediante `bindParam()` para que verifiques si no hay trampa en ese dato*.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias hermano tienes mucha razón.

Comment: @BetaM Muchas gracias por la información me ha servido mucho seguiré estudiando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias cosas:

1. La sintaxis de `BETWEEN` es errónea en tu consulta. Debe ser algo así más o menos `... BETWEEN laColumna :unaFecha AND :otraFecha`
2. La consulta en sí es errónea. Las consultas preparadas son muy simples: en la instrucción SQL debes poner un marcador (de `:nombre` en este caso) allí donde irían datos. Y luegos usas el método acordado (`bindParam()` en este caso) para pasar esos datos. Es como un contrato entre el programador y la API que dice lo siguiente: *donde he puesto estos marcadores van datos que te pasaré luego con un método bind o en el execute para que revises si no hay trampa en esos datos. Al mismo tiempo, indicaré en el bind a qué cosa corresponde cada dato **poniendo el marcador**.*  Tu código muestra confusión en ese parte, porque pasabas especie de variables en vez de marcadores, tanto en la consulta como en los bind...
3. Todo lo que pongas después de un `return` en un método no se ejecuta.
4. Poner `close()` y `=null` es redundante en este caso.

Tu método quedaría corregido así:

```
static public function modeloConsultaFechas($tablaAlumno, $colColegio, $idColegio, $colProfesor, $idProfesor, $colFecha, $fechaInicio, $fechaFinal){

    $data = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tablaAlumno WHERE $colColegio = :colColegio AND $colProfesor = :colProfesor AND $colFecha BETWEEN :fechaInicio AND :fechaFinal");

    $data -> bindParam(":colColegio", $idColegio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $data -> bindParam(":colProfesor", $idProfesor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $data -> bindParam(":fechaInicio", $fechaInicio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $data -> bindParam(":fechaFinal", $fechaFinal, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $data -> execute();

    $mData=$data -> fetchAll();

    $data=null;

    return $mData;

}
```

Comment: muchas gracias hermano.